# Scale x and y velocities to between -MAX and MAX in c++

Tags: c++, coordinates, velocity, max

I am trying to scale some x and y velocity values to be between -MAX and MAX and maintain their proportions.  The numbers can be negative, zero, or positive.  This is being used to enforce a speed limit on x and y velocities.  Here's what I've got:

```
if(abs(velocities.x) <= MAX_TRANSLATIONAL_VELOCITY && abs(velocities.y) <= MAX_TRANSLATIONAL_VELOCITY)
    return;

float higher = max(abs(velocities.x), abs(velocities.y));

velocities.x = (velocities.x / higher) * MAX_TRANSLATIONAL_VELOCITY;
velocities.y = (velocities.y / higher) * MAX_TRANSLATIONAL_VELOCITY;
```

This is not really working and the robots I'm applying it to are kind of spazzing out.  Is there a standard way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean "not really working" what did you get? what did you expect? Also - what is the type of re the fields `velocities.x` and `velocities.y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To normalize a vector you shouldn't divide its components by the maximum of any of them but by their magnitude which is the [euclidean norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Euclidean_norm) of the vector.

Actually you shouldn't check a single component, first you calculate magnitude, then if it's over MAX_MAGNITUDE, you normalize the vector and multiply it by MAX_MAGNITUDE.

```
float magnitude = sqrt(v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y);

if (magnitude > MAX_MAGNITUDE)
{
  v /= magnitude; // I'm assuming overloaded operators here
  v *= MAX_MAGNITUDE;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I knew there had to be a better way.  Thanks!